# Web Intent URL to post on facebook

Tags: facebook

I would like to know URL which is link to post to facebook. On Twitter, I can use "http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" to tweet. Although I was trying to search for one, I could not find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=YOURTITLE&p[url]=http://www.yourdomain.com&p[summary]=shortandsweetok&p[images][0]=http://www.image.to/appearwithlinkaftersharing.jpg`

This works but the images might not show properly in some cases

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore as of Jan 2020. FB shows an error when entering this URL.